# Change the time of my PC from a server of Timestamp

Tags: server, timestamp

I like to ask if it's possible to change the time of my PC from a server of timestamp in ubuntu.
Can any one give me an idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: date is the command you're looking for (https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/manage-time-in-ubuntu-through-command-line/). But I wonder why you would need that? Isn't that what NTP does? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a set top box android and I like that the stb recuperate the time from my server of timestamp and not from internet